# How do you extract specific strings from an attachment in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, attachments

I want to extract certain parts of email content and put the results into list item fields.

I want to add this to a flow I've already created that:

1. Forwards an email from a shared mailbox to a SharePoint
2. A list item is then created in that list
3. The body of the email is converted from HTML to text
4. The result of that conversion goes into a list item field
5. The contents of that list item field is then used to create a text file and attached to the list item.

For example, a string I'm interested in extracting:

- will always be one line
- will always be the last line
- begin with "Ref:"
- I want to put that line into a text field in my list item

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are string functions you can use in MS flow, you can have a check on them: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference

And here is an example of extracting last line with last fucntion
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-select-the-last-line-of-a-text-content/td-p/79575

Comment: Thank you, jerry_MSFT. Much appreciated.